# Meaning of a higher out-of-sample $R^2$ but also a higher MSPE

Tags: forecasting, descriptive-statistics

I am comparing several forecasting methods using the out-of-sample $R^2$ and MSPE. Now I have encountered situations in which the $R^2$ of a certain method is higher than that of the other, but the MSPE is higher as well. How should I interpret this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out-of-sample $R^2$ is subject to one problem: it neglects the average bias of the predictions.

Suppose you have a vector of realized values $r$ and two competing prediction vectors $f_1$ and $f_2=f_1+c$ where $c$ is some constant. Then the $R^2$ of $r$ versus $f_1$ will be exactly the same as the $R^2$ of $r$ versus $f_2$. Therefore, using out-of-sample $R^2$ is not a very good idea if you care about the bias of the predictions and not only the variance.

Now to answer your question, MSPE is not invariant to prediction bias while the out-of-sample $R^2$ is. Therefore, in general the MSPE-optimal prediction need not coincide with the out-of-sample-$R^2$-optimal prediction given a group of competing forecasts.

Comment: Consider using Theil's $U$ instead of out-of-sample $R^2$. If I remember correctly, it avoids the pitfall that the $R^2$ is subject to. Just be aware that there are a few different definitions of Theil's $U$ out there.

Comment: Thank you! However, would it still be meaningful that a forecast has a lower $R^2$, s.t. it has a lower variance? Or is the criterion entirely useless (when MSPE's are also listed)?

Comment: I would have to think about that. I would be careful about discarding the out-of-sample $R^2$ completely, perhaps it has some use sometimes.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I saw it used quite often in papers about return predictability, so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: You could post an update if you ever find out when and why it makes sense to use o.o.s. $R^2$, I would be curious to see.

Comment: In case I find out, I will!